# Are $\{\bar u, \bar u + \bar v, \bar u + \bar v + \bar w\}$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $\{\bar u, \bar v, \bar w\}$ are linearly independent. Are $\{\bar u, \bar u + \bar v, \bar u + \bar v + \bar w\}$ also linearly independent?

Is there anyone to help me? I found that this can be both independent and independent.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have
$$
\alpha u+\beta(u+v)+\gamma(u+v+w)=0
$$
Then
$$
(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)u+(\beta+\gamma)v+\gamma w=0
$$
Apply the fact that $u,v,w$ are linearly independent: this implies
\begin{cases}
\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0\\
\beta+\gamma=0\\
\gamma=0
\end{cases}
So…

Answer (score 2):

You can consider that $\beta=\{u,v,w\}$ is a base for some space V of dimension $3$. 
So, now we can take the coordinates of $\{u, u+v, u+v+w\}$ according to $\beta$.

We get $[u]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. $[u+v]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and finally $[u+v+w]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. Put all those vector in a matrix $A$ and the problem now is to ask which of these columns are base columns. So $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. You can see that $A$ is in the echelon form and get $3$ pivots. So the $3$ vectors are L.I